# Bacteria with daily bimodal energy cycle

Tags: literature

Many years ago (about 20) I was told the following story by someone who was in field of biology that at some point there was a rift between researchers of some biological organism, that they were divided on if it consumed A and produced B as the by product of the process or reverse or maybe it consumed C and D was the by product.

The divide was so severe that it was a cause of conflicts in the said circles and heated exchanges in conferences.

The issue was resolved when someone noted that holders of A to B were day workers and C to D were night workers, and that the organism is question (bacteria?) behaved one way during day and then the other during night.

I am a programmer and apologies for being so abstract but that is all I remembered/understood from the story.

**My question is :**
A) If this is a (possibly) true story?
and
B)What might be the organism in the story be and if there might be any links to any related articles?

Please feel free to edit this to make more biology friendly as I have no idea about the proper terms to use to describe the possible story that I heard.

Comment: The key term I think you're looking for is bacterial Circadian Rhythms? Most evidence of this comes from studies of photosynthetic Cyanobacteria (which makes a lot of sense) and more recently from host-associated bacteria. This recent [ASM article](https://asm.org/Articles/2021/May/Bacterial-Circadian-Rhythms-From-Lakes-to-the-Gut) talks about circadian rhythms in different types of bacteria, with links to the primary literature. No mention of anything like the story you shared, but I'm pretty intrigued by it, and would love to find out more.